# sparse matrix representation acting weirdly in c

Tags: c, matrix, sparse-matrix

Here is my code for sparse matrix implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display(int c, int sparse[][5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", sparse[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int c = 0, array[5][5] = {
        { 0, 0, 4, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 7, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 9, 0 },
        { 0, 6, 0, 3, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 2, 0, 0 }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] != 0)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }

    int k = 0, sparse[3][c];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] != 0)
            {
                sparse[0][k] = i;
                sparse[1][k] = j;
                sparse[2][k] = array[i][j];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    display(c, sparse);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried having a sparse matrix representation, which has rows, columns, value of non zero elements vertically, so if there are 7 non zero elements, then the new matrix will be created of rows, columns, value which equate to three rows, and count of columns depending on the count of non zero elements.

But it is acting weird, first I noticed a error squiggle while declaring a new matrix where I had to put column size (count of non zero elements) , but I ignored it because I couldn't think of a better approach.

It did run, but the answer was weird, although it was indeed in form I wanted, but it was mixed, I mean if while finding non zero elements the first element was `4`, then the new matrix 1st column 3rd row should have contained `4`, but it wasn't and it was all mixed up.

Then for a change, I added another non zero element, and it now shows random numbers, don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Try `void display(int c, int sparse[][c])`

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of getting the array indexing right. While the minimal change would be to change the `display` function signature to `void display(int c, int sparse[][c])`, I will prefer also to swap the indexing to better reflect how `sparse` is organized: as an array of variable size of arrays of 3 elements (row, column, value).

Comments are added in the modified places:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display(int c, int sparse[][3])  // 5 -> 3
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", sparse[j][i]);  // Indexing swapped
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int c = 0, array[5][5] = {
        {0, 0, 4, 0, 0},
        {0, 7, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 9, 0},
        {0, 6, 0, 3, 0},
        {0, 0, 2, 0, 0}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] != 0)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }

    int k = 0, sparse[c][3];  // Swap indexing to match expectation of display()
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] != 0)
            {
                sparse[k][0] = i;  // Indexing swapped
                sparse[k][1] = j;
                sparse[k][2] = array[i][j];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    display(c, sparse);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SupportUkraine: using an array of `c` rows of 3 `int` makes more sense as you can add more entries by reallocating the array, only appending new triplets.